# How to trust browser again on my iOS Device?

Tags: ios, safari, two-factor-authentication

Recently by accident I tapped "Don't trust" and every time when I login to my itunes account I need to verify this with code as it is on the image below:

[image]
[image]

**What can I do to trust that browser again or to force safari to display that dialog again to me?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Settings → Safari → Advanced → Website Data, search for ‘apple’ and delete apple.com.